# Powershell to get metadata of files

Tags: powershell, metadata

I am looking to get metadata of a specified file (or directory of files). I am specifically looking for "Program Description" on .WTV files.

I found code, but it doesn't list that attribute.  Some of that code looks like this:

```
 foreach($sFolder in $folder) 
  { 
   $a = 0 
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder) 

   foreach ($strFileName in $objFolder.items()) 
    { FunLine( "$($strFileName.name)") 
      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) 
       {  
         if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($strFileName, $a)) 
           { 
             $hash += @{ ` 
                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  =` 
                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($strFileName, $a))  
                   } #end hash 
            $hash 
            $hash.clear()
```

I can see that attribute in File explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The code you had @user1921849 has almost got it, but to address the original question more clearly you should use the Windows Shell Property System named properties, listed in the [Windows devloper documentation for WTV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/recordedtv-bumper), and used in line 4 below.

```cs
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$folder = $shell.namespace("\\MEDIA\Recorded Tv\")
$item = $folder.Items().Item('Person of Interest_WBBMDT_2013_11_26_21_01_00.wtv')
write-output $item.ExtendedProperty('System.RecordedTV.ProgramDescription')
```

*Updated URL to docs*

1. General properties list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props
2. WTV properties list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/recordedtv-bumper

Comment: This worked perfectly for pulling titles out of font files, thank you! (Used System.Title)

Answer (score 0):

Grab [TagLib# from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib) or various other places. Then check out this [blog post showing how to use TagLib# to edit MP3 tags](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=468). Hopefully, it can retrieve the WTV tag you're looking for.

Comment: I've used TagLib. That is for audio files with ID3v1 and ID3v2 tags.

Comment: Hmm, taglib-sharp claims it `is a library for reading and writing 
metadata in media files, including **video**, audio, and photo formats`.

Comment: Okay...that is different than TagLib. I'll take a look.

Comment: It looks like that works with formats like mpeg, avi, but not WTV.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shell = new-object -comobject shell.application
$ShFolder=$shell.namespace("\\MEDIA\Recorded Tv\")
$ShFile    =$ShFolder.parsename("Person of Interest_WBBMDT_2013_11_26_21_01_00.wtv")

$count = 0

while ($count -le 294)
    {
    $ShRating  = $ShFolder.getdetailsof($ShFile,$count)

    $count
    $ShRating
    $count = $count+1
    }
```

Program Description is item 272.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample code which will check all file in a folder and export a csv file with all the metadata details. Please find the following powershell script.

Step 1. Create a file **Fileproperty.ps1**

```
Import-Module ".\Module\AddModule.psm1" -Force
$commands = {
  $source = read-host "Enter folder path "  

if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($source)){
    Write-host "Invalid file path, re-enter."
    $source = $null 
     &$commands
}else{
    $output = read-host "Enter output folder path "
     if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($output)){
        Write-host "Invalid output path, re-enter."
        $output = $null
         &$commands
    }else{
        $outputfilename = read-host "Enter output file name "
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($outputfilename)){
            Write-host "Invalid file name, re-enter."
            $outputfilename = $null
             &$commands
        }else{
            Get-FileMetaData -folder $source | Export-Csv -Path $output\$outputfilename.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation   
            Write-host "Process has been done..."
        }   

    }

  }
}
&$commands
```

Step 2. Create a folder **Module**

Step 3. create another file **Module/AddModule.psm1**

```
$FunctionFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
Foreach($fileItem in @($FunctionFiles))
{
    Try
    {
        . $fileItem.fullname
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Vsts module -> Unable to import a function in file $($fileItem.fullname): $_"
    }
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function $FunctionFiles.Basename
```

Step 4. create another file **Module/Get-FileMetaData.ps1**

```
Function Get-FileMetaData
{ 
 Param([string[]]$folder) 
 $OutputList = New-Object 'System.Collections.generic.List[psobject]'
 foreach($sFolder in $folder) {
   $a = 0 
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)  
   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) 
    {  
      $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT 
      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) 
      {  
     if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) 
       { 
         $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  = 
               $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) } 
        $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash 
        $hash.clear()  
       } #end if 
   } #end for  
 $a=0 

    $OutputList.Add($FileMetaData)
   } #end foreach $file   
  } #end foreach $sfolder 
  return $OutputList
} #end Get-FileMetaData
```

Hope this will work for you.